# how can my python script react if a bot sends a message in Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, message, telethon

I am currently using telebot but I am open to other things.
and can I also filter so it only reacts if it is from a specific user (not necessary).
example:

import telebot

if message == "Thank you"

print("received message")

doing something.......

Answer (score 0):

so what I did was the following, I did not use telebot or any telegram api

i used beautifulsoup to web scrape the time of the last message send.
it looks something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


text = requests.get('Your_channellink').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
Time = soup.find_all('time' , class_ = "time")[-1].text
print(Time)
```

hope this helps, feel free to ask questions if you have them.